# Overflow in solve_bvp during "simple" differential equation system

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, overflow, ode

I would like to solve the following system of differential equation:

```
d(phi)/dz= Rcl*i
d(i)/dz = i0*exp(phi*2.3/b)
```

I tried to solve this using solve_bvp from scipy and it didn't work. To check if a solution can be found I wrote my own code and used the shooting method (initial value solver for ode system combined with optimization to find starting values) and it worked. I want to build a more complex system of differential equations, therefore it would be nice if I can use the build in functions. Can you see what I did wrong using solve_bvp or do you know ways to improve the algorithm? My code is:

**solve_bvp:**

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#define parameters
b = 50e-3
Rcl = 0.4
i0 = 1e-7

il = 0
ir = 1
#define ode system
def fun(z,y):
    phi = y[0]
    i = y[1]
    didz = i0*np.exp(phi*2.3/b)
    dphidz = Rcl*i
    dydz = np.array([dphidz,didz])
    return dydz
#Define boundary conditions
def boundary_conditions(ya, yb):

    return np.array([ya[1]-il, yb[1]-ir])

#define numerical aprameters
a = 0
b = 1
num_points = 100

#Define the initial mesh and initial guess for the solution
x_mesh = np.linspace(a, b, num_points)  # Define the interval [a, b] and the number of points
y_initial_guess = np.zeros((2, x_mesh.size))  # Initial guess for the solution
solution = solve_bvp(fun, boundary_conditions, x_mesh, y_initial_guess)
#plot
#Evaluate the solution on a finer mesh for plotting
x_fine = np.linspace(a, b, 1000)
y_fine = solution.sol(x_fine)
#%%
#Plot the solution
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x_fine, y_fine[0], label='Phi')
plt.legend()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x_fine, y_fine[1]/Rcl, label='J')
plt.legend()
```

**own code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
#define parameters
l_cl = 1       # [cm]
R_cl = 0.8     # Ohm/cm²
b = 50e-3      # 1/V
i0 = 1e-7      # A/cm²
il
ir = 1         # Target current density

num_points = 1000
step_width = l_cl / num_points
#define function to solve ode system with a given starting value
def fun(phi_start):
    state_vars = np.zeros((3, num_points))  # Single array for state variables (phi, dphidx, i)
    state_vars[0, 0] = phi_start     #define start value for phi
    state_vars[2,0] = il             #define start value for i
#calculate solution of the ode system with phi_start and give out difference between i at right boundary and ir
    for ii in range(num_points - 1):
        didx = i0 * np.exp((state_vars[0, ii]) / b * np.log(10))                        #didx
        state_vars[2, ii + 1] = state_vars[2, ii] + didx * step_width                   #i
        state_vars[1, ii + 1] = state_vars[2, ii + 1] * R_cl                            #dphidx
        state_vars[0, ii + 1] = state_vars[0, ii] + state_vars[1, ii + 1] * step_width  #phi
    return abs(state_vars[2, -1] - ir)
#find phi_start which aims to i at right boundary equals ir
x0 = 0.31
res = minimize(fun, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
phi_start_optimized = res.x
print(res.x)

state_vars = np.zeros((3, num_points))  # Single array for state variables (phi, dphidx, i)
state_vars[0, 0] = res.x
mesh = np.linspace(0,1,num_points)
#solve everything with phi_start to show solution
for ii in range(num_points - 1):
    didx = J0 * np.exp((state_vars[0, ii]) / b * np.log(10))
    state_vars[2, ii + 1] = state_vars[2, ii] + didx * step_width
    state_vars[1, ii + 1] = state_vars[2, ii + 1] * R_cl
    state_vars[0, ii + 1] = state_vars[0, ii] + state_vars[1, ii + 1] * step_width

phi = state_vars[0, :]
dphidx = state_vars[1, :]
i = state_vars[2, :]
#plot
plt.plot(mesh,phi,label='over potential')
plt.plot(mesh,i,label='i_sol')
plt.legend()
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you clarify *"it didnt work"* by providing details of what went wrong?

Comment: Full error message(s)

Comment: If the initial guess is too far away from the solution, the solver might in the first steps jump wildly and reach relatively  large numbers. Especially in exponentials you can rapidly reach overflow. You could cut off the exponent as in `exp(min(100, phi * 2.3/b))`. One would need to check the result if it reaches this cutoff value

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. The full error message is: "c:...
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  didz = J0*np.exp(phi*2.3/b)
C:\...
 RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  0.125 * h * (f[:, 1:] - f[:, :-1]))
C:\...
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  df_dy[:, i, :] = (f_new - f0) / hi
C:\...
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  r_middle /= 1 + np.abs(f_middle)" 
However, I know the solution of the odes and both variables are in the range between 0 and 1 - so there shouldnt be an overflow...

Comment: Your `y_fine[1]` is full of *nan*. Maybe because it didn't converge according to `solution.status`. You can see the nan with `solution.sol([0])`. You can set `verbose=2` so that it shows that in the first iteration it failed. You can see that the overflow is encountered since the initial value of phi. Try running `fun(0, [13586.946338469084, 0])`. Does it makes sense for phi to start so big?. Please double check if `fun` is defined correctly, if it is maybe you can play with tolerances until it converges.